# Adding fractions number yields different result in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP unexpected result of float to int type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385685/php-unexpected-result-of-float-to-int-type-cast)
>   [int((0.1+0.7)*10) = 7 in several languages. How to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439140/int0-10-710-7-in-several-languages-how-to-prevent-this)

Can someone explain me this???

```
<?php
echo (int) ((0.1 + 0.7)*10);//displays an output: `7`
?>
```

I was expecting to see `8` but I got `7` - please explain this behavior.

Is this a special feature from `PHP`? Or I didn't understand the integer type in `PHP`?

Thanks.

Comment: Why down-vote? Do you mind explaining?

Comment: possible duplicate of [int((0.1+0.7)*10) = 7 in several languages. How to prevent this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439140/int0-10-710-7-in-several-languages-how-to-prevent-this) and maybe [How computer does floating point arithmetic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033184/how-computer-does-floating-point-arithmetic)

Comment: there internal presentation is different. You may interested in reading PHP manual [page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873747/what-precaution-to-take-when-doing-something-like-price-int-0-10-7-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question in [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#warn.float-precision):

> Additionally, rational numbers that are exactly representable as
>   floating point numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or 0.7, do not have an
>   exact representation as floating point numbers in base 2, which is
>   used internally, no matter the size of the mantissa. Hence, they
>   cannot be converted into their internal binary counterparts without a
>   small loss of precision. This can lead to confusing results: for
>   example, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually return 7 instead of the
>   expected 8, since the internal representation will be something like
>   7.9999999999999991118....