# Weird calculation in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)
>   [Adding fractions number yields different result in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725708/adding-fractions-number-yields-different-result-in-php)

```
$grand_total =  (float)$subtotal_email +  (float)$delivery_email + (float)$fuel_surcharge_email - (float)$discount_coupon_email + (float)$texas_tax_email - (float)$cancel_fee_email -  (float)$refund_email - (float)$refund_tax_email - (float)$coupon_tmp;
echo (float)$subtotal_email." +  ".(float)$delivery_email." + ".(float)$fuel_surcharge_email." - ".(float)$discount_coupon_email." + ".(float)$texas_tax_email." - ".(float)$cancel_fee_email." -  ".(float)$refund_email." - ".(float)$refund_tax_email." - ".(float)$coupon_tmp." = ".(float)$grand_total;
```

When I run the above in php, I get the following output:

```
89.99 + 0 + 16.2 - 0 + 8.61 - 3 - 100 - 10 - 1.8 = -2.88657986403E-15
```

But if you look at LHS, it should be `0`, and this happens with or without float....any idea why?

Comment: [look here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point arithmetic is never that accurate. If you need to compare to zero, you need to take the different and compare it to some small number.

```
if (abs($result) < 0.00001)) {
    // it's zero
} else {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because float. Use `int`s and calculate the value with cents (* 100).